# Get focus in EditorFor MVC with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

You have a button that executes a modal window

```
    <a data-dialog="AgregarProducto" href="@Url.Action("AgregarProducto", "Salidas")" id="agregarproducto" class="dialog-window btn btn-success">Agregar Producto <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a>     

<div class="modal fade" id="AgregarProducto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te">Espere Porfavor...</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#agregarproducto').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        var title = $link.text();
        $('#AgregarProducto.modal-title').html(title);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
            $('#AgregarProducto').modal('show');
        }
        else {
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#AgregarProducto .te').html(data);
                $('#AgregarProducto').modal();
            }).success(function () { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

this is the view that runs in the browser...
[image: screenshot]

I enclose the partial view "AgregarProducto.cshtml":

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, "Producto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "true", @required = "true" , id = "editorfocus" } })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                        Agregar Producto
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    


    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
  $(function(){
   $('#AgregarProducto').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#editorfocus').focus()
   });
});

   </script>

    }
```

What you want is to focus on the EditorFor indicated by the arrow, this focus has to be executed as soon as the modal view is opened, but I'm not getting the expected result, my code does not do anything, any help for me? How can I get the focus just open the partial view "AddProduct.cshtml"?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials (and fortunately your `@section Scripts { ... }` does not work because you would be loading multiple copies of jQuery). Set the focus in your main script

Comment: Your proposed solution worked for me! propose your answer, thank you! @StephenMuecke

Comment: Your code has a `if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {` which seems odd (that will always return `false` unless there is some other code you have not shown us that is altering the `href` value). Are you trying to prevent the ajax call being made if the modal has already been loaded?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to avoid the Ajax call while the modal is open, but if the modal is open and everything works well ... what would that "IF" affect? @StephenMuecke

Comment: You handling the click event of your link. That link has `href="/Salidas/AgregarProducto"` But you have a `if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {` which is testing if the attribute is `href="#"` which its not (and never will be - unless your changing somewhere else) so its not clear why you have that `if` block.

Comment: can be, I have published all the code, should propose your answer to better understand what it suggests @StephenMuecke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166721/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fytoahse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections are not supported in partial views (which is probably fortunate in your case, since you would be loading another copy of jquery). Delete the scropts from your partial and set the focus in your main script.

```
$('#agregarproducto').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
    if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        $('#AgregarProducto').modal('show');
        $('#editorfocus').focus(); // set focus
    }
    else {
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#AgregarProducto .te').html(data);
            $('#AgregarProducto').modal();
            $('#editorfocus').focus() // set focus
        });
    }
});
```

Note that your use of the `if/else` block is unclear, since the value of `url` is always `"/Salidas/AgregarProducto"` so the code in the `else` block will only ever be executed, therefore the script can be just

```
$('#agregarproducto').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#AgregarProducto .te').html(data);
        $('#AgregarProducto').modal();
        $('#editorfocus').focus() // set focus
    });
});
```

However, if you want to avoid making ajax calls to get the same partial again if its already been loaded, then you can have a flag to indicate if its been loaded, for example

```
var isModalLoaded = false;
$('#agregarproducto').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isModalLoaded) {
        // Just show the modal
        $('#AgregarProducto').modal('show');
        $('#editorfocus').focus() // set focus
    } else {
        // Make ajax call
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            ....
        });
        isModalLoaded = true; // prevent further ajax calls
    }
});
```